# How to validate array required without other field, and vice versa?

Tags: laravel-5

I'm working on manual journaling system, so each row should have only one value, credit or debit, if credit is present then debit should null and vice versa, if credit and debit present together it should fail.

So I use `required_without` validation like this

```
'entry.*.credit' => 'required_without:entry.*.debit|nullable|numeric|digits_between:4,10',
'entry.*.debit' => 'required_without:entry.*.credit|nullable|numeric|digits_between:4,10',
```

And here is my form

```
<input type="numeric" name="entry[0][debit]" class="form-control" />
<input type="numeric" name="entry[0][credit]" class="form-control" />
<input type="numeric" name="entry[1][debit]" class="form-control" />
<input type="numeric" name="entry[1][credit]" class="form-control" />
.. so on
```

But what I get is even debit and credit is present in same row it return success.

Where I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your validation rules out that both fields are `null` at the same time but it does not restrict both of them to be present at the same time:

```
!credit && !debit --> credit = 'required', debit = 'required'
!credit &&  debit --> credit = 'nullable', debit = 'required'
 credit && !debit --> credit = 'required', debit = 'nullable
 credit &&  debit --> credit = 'nullable', debit = 'nullable'
```

So when both are present your validation simply allows both of them to be `null` or any other valid value and will hence be successful.